# How to log out as the current user from terminal, then log back in as root?

Tags: command-line, permissions

When I try `sudo su` from terminal it gives `chown: changing ownership of '/usr/bin/sudo': Operation not permitted` this error. I read several solution and one of them have told that to log out as the current user from terminal, then log back in as root. I am newer to these things. How to do that

Comment: I'm guessing those articles mean log out of the system and then login by typing "root" in the username box and then the password. What are your permissions on the /usr/bin/sudo ? Can you run " ls -l /usr/bin/sudo" ?

Comment: Please is this your pc or a remote server and what OS is this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the root, one should have to be sudoer ie., you should be logged in with a account that has administrative privilages, standard account won't work.

after that you can use

```
sudo su
```

to access root via terminal